# formtools.org preg_replace /e

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to install `formtools.org` on multiple domains, but because of its use of `preg_replace()`,  my hosting company won't allow this. I've searched their forums with not luck (I can't get access to ask a question)

I believe if the following can be rewritten using `preg_replace_callback()` this would solve all my problems.

```
    $source_content = preg_replace($search.'e', "'"
. $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
. "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('\\0', \"\n\")) .'"
. $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
. "'"
, $source_content);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service doesn't support `preg_replace()`, I would be surprised if it supports `preg_replace_callback()` (since they are essentially the same).  However, if the problem is due to the deprecated `e` modifier, `preg_replace_callback()` will help.

Using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is very simple, the second parameter is a callable function to create your replacement text.  This function takes one parameter which is an array of that match's groups.  So `reset($matches)` in my answer is similar to the `\\0` in your example.  Try this:

```
$source_content = preg_replace_callback(
  $search,
  function($matches) {
    $match = reset($matches);
    $count = substr_count($match, "\n");

    $string = "'" . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . "php'";
    $string .= str_repeat("\n", $count);
    $string .= "'" . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter) . "'";

    return $string;
  },
  $source_content
);
```

---

**Note:** since I don't have the easiest way to test this without making up your functions, expression, and `$source_content`, this is just translated from scratch.  If you have any errors, please comment (instead of downvoting) and I can work to fix them :)

Comment: Thanks for attempting to work this out with me! I wish I could be more help but this is a little advanced for me. I do get this in the error log: mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx.xxx/httpdocs/forms/global/smarty/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 278, referer: http://webdev.xxx.xxx/forms/admin/forms/edit.php?form_id=4&page=emails

Comment: Oh I think the preg_replace was fine with my service it's the /e option they don't allow.

Comment: @ScottRiggle what is `$this->_quote_replace($this->xxx_delimiter)` and anyway we can avoid this?

Comment: Sorry I have no clue what any of this is I didn't write it. It's from Smarty_Compiler.class.php

Comment: May have found something.. I searched smarty compiler class preg_replace and I see the same code I posted above on the smarty.net forum: preg_replace_callback($search, create_function ('$matches', "return '"
                                       . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
                                       . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('\$matches[1]', \"\n\")) .'"
                                       . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
                                       . "';")
                                       , $source_content)

Comment: Yea, I just saw the code in GitHub..you'll actually have to fix that in `httpdocs/forms/global/smarty/Smarty_Compiler.class.php` (or use a different server or something other than Smarty that doesn't use the `e` modifier).

Comment: This seemed to have worked. How do I give you the acknowledgement for helping me? @Sam

Comment: Glad I could help. You can +1 and accept my answer as "correct" above (one of these may require you to have more "reputation"). Welcome to StackOverflow!